# Laravel 5.4 $redirectTo not working

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I am stuck with getting the `redirectTo()` function override in my `LoginController.php` as [shown in the Laravel docs here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#included-authenticating).

My controller contains:

```
/**
 * URI where we redirect to after login
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = 'player/home';

/**
 * Set route redirect
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function redirectTo()
{
    dd("STOP"); <-- does not trigger

    if (session()->has('game.details')) {
        return route(session()->get('game.details.setup_route'));
    } else {
        return 'player/home';
    }
}
```

Why would the `dd` never trigger and the page always redirects to `player/home`? Thanks

Comment: Use `dd(session()->get('game.details.setup_route'));` and see the result!

Comment: Hi @Hiren Gohel, no difference. Still redirects to `player/home`. I tried a simpler version of your suggestion. See my question updated. Ta

Comment: Have you tried getting rid of the `protected $redirectTo` line?

Comment: So, that means `session` has not `game.details.setup_route` and that's why it redirects `player/home`

Comment: @HirenGohel The `dd` call should still occur and interrupt everything.

Comment: @ceejayoz He said `dd("STOP"); <-- does not trigger` in his question!

Comment: @HirenGohel Yes, exactly. Which is why your "session is missing game.details.setup_route` conclusion is not supported. Your proposed `dd` call should at least return `null` instead of redirecting.

Comment: Yes I just updated it to a simpler `dd`. Still not stopping

Comment: @ceejayoz I know, It's my comment before editing this question! Also, for now his function `redirectTo` not called! So, problem is at function call.

Comment: @TheRealPapa Have you called that function from your `routes` file? I mean `web/api.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I did not get the method override working, I solved it by changing these lines in the `login` method:

```
    if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
        session()->put('game.details', Game::findByUUIDOrFail($uuid));

        $this->redirectTo = route(session()->get('game.details.setup_route'));

        return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you comment 
    `$this->middleware("guest")`
in the constructor of `Auth\RegisterController` or change the line about guest middleware in the `Kernel.php` it will be worked.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the question or the linked documentation that includes the line you refer to. Could you explain your answer a little more?

Comment: had same issue before and fixed it as I mentioned. btw i was using laravel 5.5 LTS

Answer (score 0):

If you have run `php artisan auth`

change the RedirectIfAuthenticated Middleware like so

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {

            return redirect('/home');//change the redirect here
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```